# Related list is not visible in lightning mode for a user but visible in classic mode

Tags: lightning, related-list

I am trying to convert a classic application to lightning, in the process I got stuck with a weird issue. For a particular user, one child object's related list item  is not getting displayed in the related list section. But the same related list item is getting displayed when user switched back to Classic Mode.

I checked all permissions for the particular user profile like:

1. All CRUD permissions and "View All" permissions are on the profile
2. The same related list item is visible for other users with a different profile
3. On customize layout this related list section is under available category

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I have faced the same problem so this is what i did

check for the lookup field permission on the child object (It needs to be atleast read)
in classic we are able to see the related list irrespective of the fact if child object lookup field has access or not but in lightning only those related list will show up whose child object lookup field has atleast read access

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the Partner and Activities related lists on the Account page layout from classic to lightning. I found that the Partner Account related list is not available in lightning and the Activity related list was split off into a new component. This could be the same issue you are having however I can't be sure without knowing what object you are missing from your lightning page layout.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i am missing a related list of type custom object

Comment: Do you have multiple lightning pages? Could that one user be assigned to a different lightning page layout that is missing that related list?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that it is custom object, please check this KB article :https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249344&type=1

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late for the answer, but here's the resolution. Even if you add a related list by editing the page layout, it's added to the classic view. You'll need to update the Lightning Page(s) for the object to add the related list component and configure it to show the related records.

Link to SFDC documentation here (pretty unclear IMPO): [Standard Lightning Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components.htm&type=5) (Scroll down to "Related List - Single Component" on the page)

Understand that this is another weird behavior by Salesforce. Given the page layouts are shared between classic and lightning pages, as fields are shared, related lists should also be shared (unless users need extra flexibility that's provided by this feature.) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where the Related List was not available for a specific user. The reason was that the User had removed the Related list in his own configuration settings (My Settings >> Display & Layout >> Customize My Pages >> Object >> [here he removed the Related List])

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced similar issue but for classic mode, where the related lists (that appears on top) were not displayed for a specific user.

The related list were already added in My settings->Display & layout->Customize my pages. Also, the Access of object and lookup fields were present for the Profile.

Solution that worked for us was, for that user under My settings->Display & layout->Accessibility

Accessibility Mode (Classic Only) was selected. We unselected it and saved and the related list were visible.

[image]