# Entitlements - Lightning

Tags: lightning, entitlements

In Lightning it is said that entitlements related list is not available on Contact. However, i cannot see them neither on the account's related list. Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you set up and configured Entitlements as documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_setting_up.htm&type=5)? Entitlements are not enabled by default in Salesforce orgs.

Comment: Yes, i have enabled them and configured them. Also, i have created some entitlement records, but when i add the Entitlements as a related list to my Account, i don't see them in Lightning Experience. I see them in Classic.

Comment: Is this for all users or specific set of users? Can you check if [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317503&type=1&mode=1) solves the problem? _Same solution as been listed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167831/related-list-is-not-visible-in-lightning-mode-for-a-user-but-visible-in-classic) too_.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Since, this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167831/related-list-is-not-visible-in-lightning-mode-for-a-user-but-visible-in-classic?noredirect=1&lq=1) doesn't have an marked answer, I'm unable to use it to mark this question as duplicate. Hence, posting answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the Related List in Lightning, the Object's Field Level Security must be set to "Read" for all profiles within the Profile Setup. Details/ resolution mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317503&type=1&mode=1).